# Bitly URL Shortener - MISSING_ARG_LOGIN when trying to shorten URL

Tags: rest, post, postman, url-shortener, bit.ly

**Bitly** is returning the errorMessage **"MISSING_ARG_LOGIN"**. I have already received my Access Token and am doing exactly what the documentation is saying. Has anyone had this issue and found a solution. Below are some pictures of what my **Headers** and **Body** look like in my Postman Request. The documentation doesn't say I need to send any login information. I have already tried plugging my username and password in the body request but I received the same error message.

**Headers and Body in Postman Request:**

[image: Headers in Postman]

[image: Body in Postman]

Comment: Looking at the doc, you probably don't need the `host` header. If you're using v4, that has that in the URL - `/v4/shorten` Worth a try. :)

Comment: @DannyDainton I just removed the Host Key and Value and sent https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten as my request url and message is "FORBIDDEN"

Comment: Might sound odd, but can you recreate the request in a new tab and try again? Getting a different response code is a good thing though. As it's Forbidden, it will be Auth Token related now. 

Comment: I just recreated it in a new tab using the /v4/shorten and leaving out the host. Now I am getting a different response. "message": "FORBIDDEN", "resource":"bitlinks", "description":  "You are currently forbidden to access this resource."

Comment: @DannyDainton i added the /v4/shorten in the request url and kept the host. Your suggestion of opening and entering the values in a new tab fresh worked. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah cool. You can add that and just accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved when I opened a new tab and entered the Headers and Body information fresh. I also had to add the **/v4/shorten** to the end of the base URL. I was missing the **/v4/**.